# CodeDeploy not starting when adding an instance to an Autiscaling Group

Tags: autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I created the Autoscaling group and CodeDeploy on PreProd environment.
When CodeDeploy was created, this Autoscaling group was added to the deployment group.
[image]

Autoscaling group also contain lifecycle hook that was created automatically by CodeDeploy Deployment group.

[image]

This environment was created by terraform and on another account (Sandbox environment) everything works fine. But with PreProd it does not work

Here is terraform code

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "launch_template" {
  name_prefix      = "lt-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  image_id         = "ami-00000000000000000"  # Amazon Linux 2 AMI ID For Sandbox
  instance_type    = "g4dn.2xlarge"
  user_data = filebase64("${path.module}/install_codedeploy_agent.sh")
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security_group.security_group_id]
  key_name = aws_key_pair.deployer_key.key_name
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_instance_profile.name
  }

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 150
    }
  }

}

# Create a security group with public access
resource "aws_security_group" "public_sg" {
  name_prefix = "public-sg"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  # Allow SSH access from the public internet
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling_group" {
  name_prefix          = "asg-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  # availability_zones = ["us-east-1a","us-east-1b","us-east-1c"]
  desired_capacity   = 0
  max_size           = 5
  min_size           = 0

  vpc_zone_identifier = module.vpc.public_subnets
  enabled_metrics         = [ "GroupTotalInstances" ]
  launch_template {
      id      = aws_launch_template.launch_template.id
      version = "$Latest"
  }
  warm_pool {
    pool_state                  = "Stopped"
    min_size                    = 0
    max_group_prepared_capacity = 5

    instance_reuse_policy {
      reuse_on_scale_in = true
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "CodeDeploy-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}


# create a CodeDeploy application
resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "main" {
  name = "app-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
}

# create a deployment group
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "main" {
  app_name              = "${aws_codedeploy_app.main.name}"
  deployment_group_name = "deployment-group-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  service_role_arn      = "${aws_iam_role.codedeploy_service.arn}"

  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime" # AWS defined deployment config
  autoscaling_groups = [
    aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling_group.name
  ]

  # EC2 instance deployment configuration
  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type   = "IN_PLACE"
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_info {
      name = aws_lb_target_group.web.name  # Update with your ALB target group name
    }
  }
  # trigger a rollback on deployment failure event
  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events = [
      "DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE",
    ]
  }

  blue_green_deployment_config {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
    }
    green_fleet_provisioning_option {
      action = "COPY_AUTO_SCALING_GROUP"
    }
    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action                           = "TERMINATE"
      termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 2
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "web" {
  name     = "target-group-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  port     = 0000
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_lb" "web" {
  name                             = "nlb-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  internal                         = false
  load_balancer_type               = "application"
  security_groups                  = [aws_security_group.elb_sg.id]
  subnets                          = module.vpc.public_subnets
  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = true

  tags = {
    Name = "alb-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.web.arn
  port              = "0000"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.web.arn
  }
}

# create a service role for codedeploy
resource "aws_iam_role" "codedeploy_service" {
  name = "codedeploy-service-roles"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# attach AWS managed policy called AWSCodeDeployRole
# required for deployments which are to an EC2 compute platform
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "codedeploy_allow_ec2_policy_policy_attach" {
   role       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_service.name
   policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.codedeploy_allow_ec2_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "codedeploy_service" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.codedeploy_service.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "codedeploy_allow_ec2_policy" {
  name        = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-codedeploy_allow_ec2"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy to allow create EC2 instance"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
  })
}

# create a service role for codedeploy
resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role" {
  name = "ec2-roles"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# attach AWS managed policy called AWSCodeDeployRole
# required for deployments which are to an EC2 compute platform
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2_policy_attach" {
   role       = aws_iam_role.ec2_role.name
   policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ec2_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name        = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-ec2"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy to allow create EC2 instance"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
        "codedeploy:GetDeployment",
        "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig",
        "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision",
        "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
  })
}


# create an S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "codedeploy-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  acl    = "private"
}


resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ec2_instance_profile" {
  name = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-default_ec2_instance_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.ec2_instance_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_instance_role" {
  name                = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-instance_role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
  managed_policy_arns = [aws_iam_policy.microservice_policy.arn, aws_iam_policy.instance_get_ecr_policy.arn, aws_iam_policy.instance_logging_policy.arn, aws_iam_policy.instance_codedeploy_policy.arn, "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess" , "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess" , "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess" , "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"]
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "instance_get_ecr_policy" {
  name        = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-instance_get_ecr_policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for pulling image from ECR"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "instance_logging_policy" {
  name        = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-instance_logging_policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for logging into CloudWatch"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "instance_codedeploy_policy" {
  name        = "${var.project}${var.env_name}-codedeploy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for CodeDeploy"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "codedeploy:PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus",
          "codedeploy:Get*",
          "codedeploy:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.b.bucket_domain_name}/*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "ec2:DescribeTags",
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

module "security_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"

  name        = "http-access-${var.project}${var.env_name}"
  description = "Security group for example usage with EC2 instance"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ingress_rules       = ["https-443-tcp", "http-80-tcp", "all-icmp" ,"ssh-tcp"]
  egress_rules        = ["all-all"]
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = [
    {
      from_port   = 0000
      to_port     = 0000
      protocol    = "tcp"
      description = "User-service ports"
      cidr_blocks = "0.0.0.0/0"
    },
  ]
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer_key" {
  key_name   = "key${var.env_name}-deployer-key"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "elb_sg" {
  name        = "allow_all_access_to_elb"
  description = "Allow ALL inbound connections to ELB"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id


  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0000
    to_port     = 0000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_all_sg"
  }
}
```

Now I'm stuck. Maybe I miss some permissions.
I already cleaned up all infrastructure and create again. The same situation. On sandbox account it works, but with PreProd does not.
Please can someone guide me to find reason, why when Autoscaling is  scaling up CodeDeploy deployment does not start.

It can be succesfull only after such actions:

- Scale up Autoscaling group
- Start CodeDeploy manually

Then deploy will begin and will be successful.

Thank you for helping